# error while setting file capabilities in Docker

Tags: docker, linux-capabilities

I'm trying to set the setfcap capability within a docker image. When I try to run the command `setcap cap_setfcap=eip /usr/sbin/setcap`, I get the following error:

> Failed to set capabilities on file `'/usr/sbin/setcap'` (Invalid
>   argument)

Comment: Can you please post the output of `docker info` on the host?

Comment: @joeinb I figured it out. if the storage driver is aufs setcap doesn't work so i had to change my storage driver to devicemapper